# python: How do I capture a variable declared in a non global ancestral outer scope?

Tags: python, scope

Given:

```
def f():
    x = 0
    def g():
        h()
    def h():
        x += 1
        print(x)
    g()

>>> f()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 8, in f
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in g
  File "<stdin>", line 6, in h
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'x' referenced before assignment
>>>
```

How can I make `h` see the `x` variable?

Thanks.

**EDIT**

Should have mentioned it earlier, I am using Python 2.7.3

Comment: seems like almost-global to me... bad idea? (but still good question)

Comment: @Shep: you want a different x for each f() call, so a global variable would not do.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can make `x` a [function attribute](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0232/):

```
def f():
    f.x = 0
    def g():
        h()
    def h():
        f.x += 1
        print(f.x)
    g()
```

Also, as of Python 3, you can use [`nonlocal`](http://docs.python.org/release/3.0/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-nonlocal-statement) keyword.

Comment: If you attach it to `g` or `h`, you get a seperate `x` for every call to `f` rather than a global one that's scopes as `f` and thus probably global. That's especially important if `g` or `h` end up as closures (even indirectly, e.g. by being added as callback).

Answer (score 9):

In Python 3 just use `nonlocal`:

```
def f():
    x = 0
    def g():
        h()
    def h():
        nonlocal x
        x += 1
        print(x)
    g()
f()
```

Comment: he's using print() means the OP is using python 3.x only.

Comment: It's worth mentioning. But `print()` with one argument actually works on python 2 although I also agree he is using python 3.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary: Actually, print() is valid syntax in Python 2.x as well.

Answer (score 8):

If you're using Python 3, you use the `nonlocal` keyword. Put `nonlocal x` at the beginning of function `h`. If you're using Python 2.x, a workaround is making `x` a list with one element, so you can modify it:

```
def f():
    x = [0]
    def g():
        h()
    def h():
        x[0] += 1
        print x[0]
    g()

f()
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't we put `x` as function arguments as workaround

```
def f():
    x = 0
    def g():
        h(x)
    def h(x):
        x += 1
        print(x)
    g()

f()
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest is to use a dict or empty class, e.g.:

```
class Empty:
    x = 0

def f():
    closure1 = dict(x=0)
    closure2 = Empty()
    def g(): h(x)
    def h(x):
        closure1["x"] += 1
        closure2.x += 1
    g()
    print closure1["x"], closure2.x
```

Although many good solutions were already provided, they have corner cases:

- nonlocal, per Ashwini, is Python 3.x only
- function attribute, per ovgolovin, will fail is `f` is redefined and later called by reference